# Find probability distribution for random number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do this.

So I have a random number $q$ which is uniformly distributed on the interval 
$[-0.5, 0.5]$

Then:
$\theta = 2\times\arcsin(2q)$ have the probability distribution $\ p(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{4}\times\cos(0.5\theta)$

I think I need to calculate $\dfrac{dq}{d\theta}$. But I can't see how. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to show that $p\in[-.5,.5] \wedge \theta=2 arcsin(2q) \Rightarrow p(\theta) = 2 cos(\theta/2)$? Are you trying to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Sorry, might have been abit sloppy when reading over befor posting. I need to prove that θ=2×arcsin(2q) have the probability distribution p(θ)=2×cos(0.5θ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\theta$ strictly increases with $q$. Hence we can use:-

(Let $g$ and $p$ be probability densities for $q$ and $\theta$ respectively.)
$$|p(\theta)d\theta|=|g(q)dq|$$
where $q=\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and $g(q)=1$ for $-0.5 \le q\le 0.5$.

So $dq=d(\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}})=\frac{1}{4}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$

Therefore $p(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$

There appears to be extra incorrect information in the question.

Comment: My bad! It was suppose to be p(θ)=1/4×cos(0.5θ). Which will make your answer correct. I wrote 2 for some reason. But anyway, thank you. It made sense now :)